# __str__ not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, string, class

Hello  I'm having trouble with the __str__ when I try to print my object.  The interpreter is telling me "TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"

This is the code that I'm trying to run!

```
    'My Practice Class' 
    class Directory:
        'A Simple Directory Class'

        def __init__(self, name, parent):
            self.name = name
            self.parent = parent

        def __str__(self):
            return 'I am %s a Child directory of %s' % (self.name, self.parent)

        def __repr__(self):
            return 'Directory(%r)' % self.name
```

---

```
print a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<\stdin>", line 1, in <\module>  
  File "myclass.py", line 14, in \__str\__  
    def \__repr\__(self):  
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Thank you

Comment: It looks OK. Can you add the traceback for the error you are getting?

Comment: Your class works for me (as posted) - both ```__str__()``` and ```__repr__()```  Please post the statements that create the instance and use the methods.

Comment: Hm so what the heck could it be then?

Comment: @Matt, post the complete program, so people can run exactly the same thing you ran.  By "complete" I mean enough code to provoke the error - no more, and no less ;-)

Comment: What is self.name? It looks like it's the `__repr__` method of that object that's causing trouble.

Comment: Could you include the actual file content? The content you show is indented and have 13 lines. The traceback points to the line 14.

Comment: I just declared an object a = Dictionary('Home','Root'), then say  print a.  I mean I don't really have a file that implements it.  It's just this much code from the header, and an import, declaration, and print in it's main.

Comment: Well now it's working so I don't know what the heck sorry everyone!  I just re-booted and everything is fine lol.  WEIRD!

Comment: Were you doing this in an interactive shell?  You could have shadowed/clobbered something important.

Comment: or are you importing and failed to call `reload(xxx)`.  Calling `import xxx` will only load it if not previously loaded, so python might have been seeing old code, even when you had saved (but not reloaded) new code.

Comment: Yes I was doing it in the interactive shell.  I didn't realize that import wouldn't update the interactive shell if I modify the file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I unload (reload) a Python module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437589/how-do-i-unload-reload-a-python-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Moved from comments as this might be a helpful sign post question]

If you are importing a module that you are working on calling

```
import xxx
```

a second time does not re-import the changed file (python is trying to be clever, sees you already have that module loaded short-circuts the process).  What was going on was that you were changing the file, but python was never seeing those changes.

To reload a module call

```
reload(xxx)
```

Also becareful if you imported things as

```
from xxx import yyy
```

Calling `reload xxx` will not affect `yyy` you would need to do

```
reload(xxx)
yyy = xxx.yyy
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me:

```
>>> class Directory:
        'A Simple Directory Class'

        def __init__(self, name, parent):
            self.name = name
            self.parent = parent

        def __str__(self):
            return 'I am %s a Child directory of %s' % (self.name, self.parent)

        def __repr__(self):
            return 'Directory(%r)' % self.name


>>> a = Directory('Name', 'Parent')
>>> print(a)
I am Name a Child directory of Parent
>>> 
>>>
```